# do any mongodb ORMs allow you to alias fields?

Tags: ruby, node.js, mongodb, orm

I just watched this: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/38467892360/mongodb-schema-design-insights-and-tradeoffs-from

One suggestion that came out of the talk: in docs that will be replicated many times, try to make the field names as small as possible:

> Reduce collection size by always using short field names as a
>   convention. This will help you save memory over time.

Choose "u" over "publicationUrl". Makes sense if you're talking about millions of rows. However, big readability problem there. It might be obvious that the value is a url, but what sort of url is it?

This might be solvable in the ORM though. Do any ORMs that interface with MongoDb allow you to say that 'u' in the db would map to 'publicationUrl' in the code? When you have things like `a.u` in code, that's pretty poor readability; `article.u` isn't much better.

(Ruby and node.js tags are there because those are the languages that I work with mongo in. Feel free to add tags.)

Comment: I don't know of any for ruby and node.js but my 2 cents is that the over head between `u` and `publicationUrl` from my own tests is extremely small and normally you either trade space or speed in terms of having to house this alias ability for huge collections and high load sites. I prefer to trade a few extra bytes than have to deal with the application hair ball

Comment: I have worked on a project where single and double character field names were necessary due to the the volume of data (billions of records generated nightly). From the beginning we aliased the names with symbols and used a hash to map the symbols to the field names. This was acceptable, but we also stuck with the MongoDB driver for Ruby and didn't use an ORM.

Comment: @cfeduke ah that seems like a good alternative, thanks

Comment: @Sammaye but on the ORM side `myHugeVariable` is effectively the same as `m`. But inside the db, they aren't especially if you're working with many many records. Her point was that as you start to strain memory, field names can become an issue.

Comment: Indeed they can, i.e. `my_awesome_field_that_is_really_big` would strain memory massively but the difference between something relatively small is...well small if you set-up your network right. This of course changes for nested nested nested subdocuments. You have got to remember that for every document your app pulls out (dependant upon memory management here) it will need to store two copies of your hash, one of the original map and one of your new map and then it will need to translate etc, it is like making two extra layers really.

Comment: @Sammaye words, yes I understood many of those words; lol you went over my head man but I will keep that in mind

Comment: Whoops when I said it would strain memory I meant storage, but that is true, memory is also a problem here since the working set would be put up

Comment: @Sammaye yeah I think that's what she was talking about in her discussion; things like map/reduce get ugly when you are working with large numbers of docs with large field names -- I think that's what she meant anyway. Time to watch again.

Comment: I must be honest I haven't seen the presentation, it was too long so I watched the first 5 mins then clicked close on firefox. It is true that if you are dealing with that many docs in a MR but then you should probably seek to do an incrementing MR then since you are most likely getting more problems than that, I mean the main thing is the storage and working set, since of course, MongoDb stores the field name in the index too. But it is all about trade offs and it is per app (and field name) exclusive which is best.

Comment: As an actual implementation Wibidata (a third party tool built on top of HBase) does this very same column family single character aliasing as a performance best practice. I know MongoDB isn't HBase but generally the patterns of implementation are similar across these big data solutions so aliasing can't be very far off the mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to with the Ruby ORM [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html). Here is an example straight from the [docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields):

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :n, as: :name, type: String
end

band = Band.new(name: "Placebo")
band.attributes #=> { "n" => "Placebo" }

criteria = Band.where(name: "Placebo")
criteria.selector #=> { "n" => "Placebo" }
```

I have used Mongoid on quite a few projects (albeit, all small ones) and really enjoy working with it. The docs are really great, and there is a section in the docs about performance as well.

Answer (score 2):

Per [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongoose-orm/c68ZdYBAsVM/KgRH4clNYSQJ), [Mongoose allows for virtual field](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) names with getters and setters.  Unfortunately virtuals can't be used in queries, and other server side operations such as map-reduce. The discussion also suggests [this plugin](https://github.com/ramiel/Alias-Field-Mongoose-plugin) for aliases as well which seems to address the query issue, but I suspect that it would also have trouble with more complex server side operations.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine MongoDB ODM allows you to set an alias for your field while your object including getters and setters can remain readable f.e.:

/** @String(name="pUrl") */
private $publicationUrl;

[Annotations Reference — Doctrine MongoDB ODM 1.0.0-BETA2 documentation — Field](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#field)